# HTML to PDF Converter in PDF.co Zapier plugin

Tags: html, pdf, converters, zapier

I'm trying to set PDF.co Zapier plugin to fill HTML Template with json datas in order to create PDF.
I selected "2. HTML to PDF Converter in PDF.co" action.

In "Set up action" section, I filled HTML Template Id field with the template ID I created on app.pdf.cp/template/html.

I filled HTML Template Data field with a basic json ({"test":"hello"}).

Here is the screenshot of "Set up action" section :[image]

But, when I submit "Test and review", I have this error message :

[image]

Here is the HTML template I use in PDF.co application :

[image]

Otherwise, PDF creation from this template works perfectly well from PDF.co application. The issue seems to be on Zapier side.
What do I do wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. PDF.co support answered me that it was an actual bug on their side. Plugin works well now.